# Стандартный фон в приложении под iPad

Tags: ipad, cocoa, ios, iphone

Во многих приложениях вижу один и тот же серый фон с эффектом ткани. Как мне использовать такой фон в моем приложении?

Вот фон, о котором я говорю (на примере приложения Keynote):
[image]

Comment: ![alt text](/upfiles/img.png) <br />
Ограничение на размер файла - 100кб, потому пришлось настолько уменьшить. Надеюсь все видно :)

Comment: Сохранил, увеличил, ничего не видно... <br />
По порядку: тыкаем на выбор бэкграунда, затем в выпадающем списке выбираем iPhone SDK и в списке бэкграундов выбираем scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor

Comment: Не могли бы вы проверить ссылку на изображение?

Answer (score 1):

```
[UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor]
```

См. также http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/UIColor